# Why does XGrabKeyboard() not register some keyboard inputs?

Tags: c++, c, x11, keyboard-events, keyboard-input

I'm a beginner in programmation with C++ and for two weeks I'm writting a script to play a space-shooter for 2 players on a same keyboard.

For game display, I'm using NCURSES and for keyboard inputs, I'm using X11. For the start, I have a persistent problem with keyboard inputs.

With a friend, we wrote this function :

```
//earlier in the script :

Display *dpy; 

if (NULL==(dpy=XOpenDisplay(NULL))) {

    perror("Connexion problem");
    exit(1);

}

XGrabKeyboard(dpy, DefaultRootWindow(dpy), True, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync, CurrentTime);


//the function (keysPressed is just an array to store keyboard inputs) :

void getKBinput(bool (&keysPressed)[128], Display* dpy){

    XEvent ev;
    int kc;

    if (XPending(dpy)){

        XNextEvent(dpy, &ev);

        switch (ev.type) {

            case KeyPress:

                kc = ((XKeyPressedEvent*)&ev)->keycode;
                keysPressed[kc] = true;
                break;

            case KeyRelease:

                kc = ((XKeyReleasedEvent*)&ev)->keycode;
                keysPressed[kc] = false;
                break;

            case Expose:

                while (XCheckTypedEvent(dpy, Expose, &ev));
                break;

            case ButtonPress:

            case ButtonRelease:

            case MotionNotify:

            case ConfigureNotify:

            default:

                break;

            }
        }
    }
}


//later in the script :

XUngrabKeyboard(dpy, CurrentTime);

if (XCloseDisplay(dpy)) {

    perror("You can't deconnect to the server");
    exit(1);

}
```

I'm using this function inside a loop-while to move each spaceship depending of what players are pressing each frame.

However, when I'm using specific keys' mixes, the program doesn't take care of some keys (so he doesn't register them in the boolean array keysPressed).

For exemple, when the player 1 is pressing the key "D" and the key "C" at the same moment, the player 2 can't use the key "up" or the key "!" (but the player 2 can use the key "left" and the key "down" at the same time without problem).

To get a better view of what this script is doing I rewritted this part in an external file to print the keys pressed and the keys released:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    Display *dpy;
    XEvent ev;
    char * s;
    unsigned int kc;
    int quit = 0;

    if (NULL==(dpy=XOpenDisplay(NULL))) {
        perror(argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    XAutoRepeatOff(dpy);

    XGrabKeyboard(dpy, DefaultRootWindow(dpy), True, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync, CurrentTime);

    for (;!quit;) {

        XNextEvent(dpy, &ev);

        switch (ev.type) {

        case KeyPress:

             kc = ((XKeyPressedEvent*)&ev)->keycode;
             s = XKeysymToString(XKeycodeToKeysym(dpy, kc, 0));

             if (s) printf("KEY PRESS:%s\n", s);

             if (!strcmp(s, "q")) quit=~0;

             break;

        case KeyRelease:

             kc = ((XKeyReleasedEvent*)&ev)->keycode;
             s = XKeysymToString(XKeycodeToKeysym(dpy, kc, 0));

             if (s) printf("KEY RELEASE:%s\n", s);

        case Expose:

             while (XCheckTypedEvent(dpy, Expose, &ev));
             break;

        case ButtonPress:

        case ButtonRelease:

        case MotionNotify:

        case ConfigureNotify:

        default:

            break;

        }
    }

    XUngrabKeyboard(dpy, CurrentTime);

    XAutoRepeatOn(dpy);

    if (XCloseDisplay(dpy)) {

        perror(argv[0]);
        exit(1);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

This confirmed my problem. Because my computer is old (and some keys work horribly) I tested this script on other computers to fall on same outputs.

I searched in x11 documentation (maybe not correctly ?), a function to unlock every mixes between keys or an other way to get around this limitation. I found nothing. Should I use an other library for keyboard inputs ?

Sorry for my poor english (and the potential mistakes) I made my best to be understandable. Thank you for your reading.

Comment: Have you considered not writing with X11? Maybe try SDL/SFML or some other library? They're well tested and provide great support for such features, as well as nicer naming schemes

Comment: Thank you for your quick participation, I'm going to look if these libraries could be useful.

Comment: Finally, for those who will fall on this topic later and who need an answer, I identified the problem. I wrote the same program with SDL (and I came back on the same outputs). With these results, I realized that we can't solved this situation with software. It's a hardware problem called "ghosting keyboard" and only gamer keyboards are built to avoid this. You can find a lot of explanations about this on the Web.